# How to implement a gradient color picker in code?

Tags: graphics, color-picker

I'm wanting to program something like Photoshop's gradient color picker. I've been googling but can't find anything. Do you guys know how to do it?

Comment: Any specific color model (ie. rgb, lab, cmyk, etc.)?

Comment: If you are thinking web based you could get some ideas from this JQuery plugin http://www.eyecon.ro/colorpicker/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit out of date (and .NET if that's your choice of framework), but in the past I've implemented an app with this [ColorPicker](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/selection/dotnetcolorpicker.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I remember hacking up something like it with a static image and `getPixel`.